# First value empty while reading cells of a html table's row using Selenium/java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, html-table

I have a very strange problem with reading data from a table row. This particular row has a few cells. First two are datetime (03/27/2017 08:30), code:

```
<div class="container-fluid container-full" id="OUTPUTSECTION">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="1080" class="table table-condensed-extra table-striped table-hover">
                        <tbody><tr><td colspan="50" style="text-align: center" class="tableHead">Document History Report</td></tr><tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">Start Time</span></td>
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">End Time</span></td>
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">Machine</span></td>
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">Site</span></td>
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">Operator</span></td>
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">Disposition</span></td>
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">Status</span></td>
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">Result</span></td>
                        <td class="tableSubhead">
                        <span class="table-header">Data Source</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tableTextWhite">
                        <td align="CENTER">03/27/2017 08:30</td>
                        <td align="CENTER">03/27/2017 08:30</td>
                        <td align="CENTER">TMX_01</td>
                        <td align="CENTER">Techmex</td>
                        <td align="CENTER">Anne</td>
                        <td align="CENTER">Completed</td>
                        <td align="CENTER">Good</td>
                        <td align="CENTER">Finished</td>
                        <td align="CENTER">D:\TMX_01\WORKING\27003001.txt/1</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        parent.endTimems = new Date().getTime();
                        if( parent.startTimems )
                        {
                            parent.timeTakenms = parent.endTimems - parent.startTimems;
                            parent.startTimems = null;
                            if (parent.debugdiv && parent.timeTakenms )
                                parent.debugdiv.innerHTML = parent.timeTakenms/1000 + ' sec';
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

A basic table really... Here is my method, which reads that code using xpath.

```
public String[] getTimesFromDocumentHistoryReportPage() {
    String XPATH_DETAILS_BASE = "//div['OUTPUTSECTION']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td";
    String[] data = new String[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        String XPATH_DETAILS = XPATH_DETAILS_BASE + "[" + (i + 1) + "]";
        data[i] = getElement(By.xpath(XPATH_DETAILS)).getText();
    }
    return data;
}
```

For data[0] I am getting an empty value, even though copying and pasting the html and xpath into one of the online testers: videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi returns a valid result. Next pass returns data[1], which has correct value. What am I missing here?

Comment: HTML code which you have shown, does it belong to row 3 <tr> of the table?

Comment: Yes. This is row 3. Second cell is is read correctly. The rest of the cells as well.

Comment: have you manulaly tried this xpath "//div['OUTPUTSECTION']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]"

Comment: Yes, //div['OUTPUTSECTION']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1] works just fine. But when I run the test Selenium picks up empty value...

Comment: manual  xpaths "..td[1]" and "..td[2]" return same values?

Comment: Can you try putting some wait before going into `for` loop and also before `data[i]` ?

Comment: In this case yes, because it's the same datetime in both cells. But if I put different values in the table then xpaths return correct values as well.

Comment: so ur current method returns values like {null,'03/27/2017 08:30'}, plus I'm little confused why do you say data[2] ? when the data should only have data[0] and data[1].

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes. Should be data[0], data[1]. And yes. It returns {"","03/27/2017 08:30"}

Comment: Have you tried use javascript to get text? also please try to loop this : int[] index = {0, 0, 1}; and show us the result

Comment: No javascript attempts yet. I've tried the loop above and the result is {"","03/27/2017 08:30"}

Comment: Can you try fetching values in reverse order as data[0] for element 2 and data[1] element 1;   let's see what you get then?

Comment: I'm getting the same results in reverse order. {"03/27/2017 08:30",""}

Comment: Are you getting Anne as the third value? You need to update your question with more details on what results you are getting. A link to the page or some more of the relevant HTML would be useful. We're kinda searching blind at this point. What is `//div['OUTPUTSECTION']` supposed to do?

Comment: I have added as much code as I could. And yes, I am getting all values from this row, except the first one. When fetching the cell values manually with xpaths I am getting all values, including first one.

Comment: @Piasek why only 2 results? there 3 indexes from the array i gave you above.

Comment: @SDBot first two are empty.

Comment: try this : data[i] = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].text;",driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH_DETAILS)));

Comment: Can you increase your loop values to >2, and post the results. Preferably equal to row size

Comment: I did and I got all values except first one. 
@SDBot I've tried your solution and it returns null for each cell . I also had to wrap it with String.valueOf().

Comment: It's kind of bizarre; that your able to get values manually for that particular element and while generating same xpath dynamically it doesn't work, is there no way you can provide the URL?

Comment: I cannot provide url. This is not a webpage, but a customer report from a web interface of an app. Unfortunately I cannot share any more code due to company policy :(

Comment: @Piasek sry my js is wrong it's "arguments[0].textContent" not "arguments[0].text", can you please try again

Comment: I've tried and it works for all cells except first one... I am out of ideas as well. I've tried everything I could think of and there seems to be no explanation to this issue. The code looks completely normal. I can fetch the value manually, but when Selenium does it, it fails :(

Comment: ok, if you're not giving up yet. try get the page source from selenium driver.getPageSource();, then see if the data you're looking for is there, if it is, you can get it via regex or html parser.

Comment: Wow, I did that and...

    `<td align="CENTER">03/28/2017 07:05</td>
    <td align="CENTER">03/28/2017 07:05</td>`

What is going on here?! The datetime is there...

Comment: @SDBot Using regex on the code extracted from getPageSource() returns correct results! I have both datetimes read correctly from the table.

Comment: @Piasek glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the piece of code code I was struggling with:

```
<tr class="tableTextWhite">
  <td align="CENTER">03/27/2017 08:30</td>
  <td align="CENTER">03/27/2017 08:30</td>
  <td align="CENTER">TMX_01</td>
  <td align="CENTER">Techmex</td>
  <td align="CENTER">Anne</td>
  <td align="CENTER">Completed</td>
  <td align="CENTER">Good</td>
  <td align="CENTER">Finished</td>
  <td align="CENTER">D:\TMX_01\WORKING\27003001.txt/1</td>
</tr>
```

This is my final, working solution as proposed by @SDBot:

```
    public String[] getTimesFromDocumentHistoryReportPage() {
        String htmlSource = driver.getPageSource();
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td align=\"CENTER\">(.+?)</td>");
        final String[] tagValues = new String[2];
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlSource);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            matcher.find();
            tagValues[i] = matcher.group(1);
        }
        return tagValues;
    }
```

The method does a search within given htmlSource and finds all instances of data (.+?) located between  and  html tags. This was enough in my case.

Since I am interested in first two cell values it is sufficient to make 2 iterations and return result. Test passed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure what happened, but since you successfully get the data from page source, I suggest you paste it to html parser (I use jsoup) then extract the data.

```
public String[] getTimesFromDocumentHistoryReportPage() {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
    Elements elements = document.select("#OUTPUTSECTION .tableTextWhite > td");
    String[] data = new String[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        data[i] = elements.get(i).text()
    }
    return data;
}
```

I'm not on my computer now and I haven't tried my code yet, so maybe there is syntax errors, do let me know and I'll fix it.

you can download Jsoup here :https://jsoup.org/download

Comment: Since you previous solution seems to do the trick, I will not pursue this one. We have a certification process in place for external libraries. It's quite troublesome to go through.

Comment: thats ok, you can post your on solution here and mark it as the correct answer.